# Standard / Interpretation of dip switch on diagram

Tags: switches, diagram, dip

I've managed to get myself thoroughly confused now.

Given the following diagram for a dip switch, which way is up / on?

[image]

Do you read the above as:

- 1 = On
- 2,3,4 = Off

or as:

- 1 = Off
- 2,3,4 = On

Comment: read both ways until further information reveals the correct choice ... if further info is unavailable then choose 1 is OFF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The small white square within the black opening is the part of the switch you slide, so white upward is on.

1 is off.  2,3,4 is on.

I have also seen the black and white used in the opposite way, where the small square is black in a white opening.

Comment: The first part would be an answer... if only you did not say exact opposite in the next sentence. As it is, it basically means "I have no idea"

Comment: @Maple. I was saying that the black/white isn’t important, it is the small square that indicates the position of the switch.